# Where are custom menu items saved?

Tags: menuitem, spss

I am creating several custom menu items in SPSS to access several custom created SPSS scripts and syntax.

In order to aviod re-creating all the menu items on every single machine. Is there a file where these menus are saved when created that can be copied and transfered to other machines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SPSS Statistics has two different mechanisms for custom menus.  If you are using View>Menu editor, the customizations are stored in the Registry (on Windows).  The Registry key is version specific, and this structure can change from release to release.

For dialogs (and their menu items) created by the Custom Dialog Builder, the pieces are stored under the ext\lib directory.  By default, that is under the Statistics installation directory, but it can be elsewhere according to the settings of the users SPSS_CDIALOGS_PATH environment variable or in the APPDATA area.  Custom dialogs are stored as a properties file and an xml file with the same name as the dialog box.  There may also be an htm help file for the dialog.  If the dialog is translated, there will be localized versions of the properties and htm files stored in the same location.

On startup, Statistics searches these directories and adds the relevant menu items to the display.

Comment: Thanks.

Managed to find the Registery keys in:
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\JavaSoft\Prefs\com\ibm\/S/P/S/S\/Statistics\19.0\ui\doc_types\dataeditor\menus